Command line ReadyAPI test case stops after initialising Java
When I try to hit ReadyAPI test case from command line, then it stops after initialising the Java. The same test case when run via GUI mode, runs perfectly fine. Can someone help, what I am doing wrong here?
Command line:
/Applications/ReadyAPI-3.51.0.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/testrunner.sh -s TestSuite -c TestCase -r -a -j "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML -E Environment /Users/soapUI/ProjectFiles/ClientAPISmokeTest.xml -Dreadyapi.migration.ignore=true
Last few lines of Outcome:
23:01:38,274 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Adding listeners from [/Applications/ReadyAPI-3.51.0.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/listeners/demo-listeners.xml]
23:01:38,277 WARN  [SoapUIJasperReportManager] The report directory is not specified. The default report directory will be used.
23:01:38,435 INFO  [DashboardDbInitializer] H2 migration check was performed using [H2 Migration] manager class: H2MigrationOrchestratorImpl
23:01:38,582 DEBUG [license] Default license portal endpoint: https://login.slm.manage.smartbear.com:443
23:01:38,583 DEBUG [license] Default license API endpoint: https://api.slm.manage.smartbear.com:443
23:01:38,846 INFO  [PluginManager] 3 out of 3 plugins have been loaded in 172 ms.
23:01:41,853 INFO  [license] User has logged in.
I can see that it starts java in my system and then it stops after this step
Tried to set the JAVA_HOME and its located fine.
Tried to run the test from ReadyAPI GUI and it worked fine too
